# Etymology of "-by" suffix in proper nouns

Tags: meaning, etymology

I am curious to find out about the etymology of the suffix **-by** in proper nouns such as the following:

> Hornby, Gatsby, Bartleby, Barlby, Selby, Osgodby, Keisby, and Hanby

Comment: GR. Borrowed from the Old Norse _býr_ meaning ‘town’ or ‘dwelling’ (also the modern Danish word for a town or city, and the Swedish and Norwegian word for a hamlet).

Comment: Which General Reference contains this information?  I see in the OED that *-by* in names is from an obsolete noun *by* meaning "A place of habitation; a village or town", which appears have the etymology you suggest.  But I was unable to find this information in any online sources.

Comment: The suffix *-by* comes from *búa* "to dwell", which is ultimately related to *be* (*Oxford English Dictionary*). It seems to be unrelated to *burg/borough/-bury*, which comes from *berg-* "to protect, shelter".

Comment: @snailboat, it is perhaps only peripherally GR, but _Derby_, probably the most widely known and used name in _-by_, is included in etymonline with this etymology of _-by_. I would assume that if one were familiar with such names as Bartleby, Osgodby, Keisby, and Hanby (of which I’ve never heard of the latter three), one would also be familiar with Derby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*-by* in a place name indicates a name given by the Vikings when they settled in Britain. The suffix *bȳ* meaning "farmstead", "settlement" in Old Norse.
So *Hornby* was "Horn's farm" (*Horn* being the name of the man who owned the place), *Barlby* was Bald's (also spelt Badulf) farm, *Selby* the settlement by the willow trees (*Sele* - Old Norse for a willow tree), etc...
Place names with *-by* will be found mostly in Yorkshire and the north of England, where the Vikings penetrated into Britain in the 8th-9th centuries.

It used to be common for people to be given the name of their birth place when they moved away, therefore those names are also surnames, or even first names (Shelby, for example).

There's a good [online free tool](http://kepn.nottingham.ac.uk/) to find out about England's place names.  I couldn't find there two of the names you give (Bartleby and Gatsby) which of course doesn't mean they don't exist as places.

Comment: If memory serves, the character Gatsby was supposed to have invented that name to give himself airs of Englishness.